# Why am I getting this error using Lambda?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I have been following a tutorial for Tkinter and am running into a problem.

This is the line of code:

```
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=Lambda: button_click(1))
```

This is exactly the same as that which is used in the youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA&list=WL&index=2&t=1171s).

But when I run it, I get this error in Pycharm:

```
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/Tkinter Tutorial/TkinterTest.py", line 15
    button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=Lambda: button_click(1))
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: `lambda`, lowercase.

Comment: Thank you so much!
The tutor is using a text editor that makes it look like a capital L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are new to Python: Python is case-sensitive and almost every keyword is written in lower-case. This also applies for "lambda", so you just have to change your casing and it should work.

```
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
```